# Sync contacts to our own web server

Tags: android

i wanted to create a sample application to sync my contacts to my web server. Are there any good tutorial to learn, how to sync my contacts in my emulator to my own web server..?? Would appreciate your kind help.

Comment: try funnabol sync server

Comment: you welcome, have you visited this ? http://funambol.com/

Comment: no did not know about this site before. Going through it now. The app which they have done is so huge, my sample app deals with only contacts. This is what i'm aiming for as of now. :)

Comment: @Android: if you get to know any, please let me know. There are few modifications i'm planning to do for the current project. As of now I just wanted with contacts. And thank you again, appreciate your kind help

Comment: well without seeing your code, i can not suggest you anything. can you upload your code ?

Comment: I'm not supposed to do that, says my organisation. My role as of now is to develop a sample app that sync's contacts to the web server, so was finding some proper source for it, and i'm still on hunt. And if there exists such small application source also then also fine.

Comment: that is ok, I thought you are getting problem in your code, so I asked for it.

Comment: @Android no no, that was not the issue. Thank you again, will update you if I find any.

Comment: there are few desktop sync application, how far does it differ from mobile devices i'm not able to make out. check out the following link http://www.webgear.co.nz/Products/GOContactSync.aspx

Comment: that looks like nice API

Comment: wish such simple apps in android. May be there are such apps, a proper R&D can get me there.

Comment: the more R & D you do , the more you learn

Comment: Nice to meet you. I am from Gujarat-Ahmedabad.

Comment: Nice to meet you too. I have friends from your place. Well how long are you working in android PF. ?

Comment: Just 8 Months only. how about you ?

Comment: I have also a friend from Chennai, working in Photon Company, have you heard about it ?

Comment: hi @Android, sorry for such a long gap, was out so couldn't turn up, I am doing good. How are you?

Comment: sorry every mails are blocked here, I will do it from my home.

Comment: hi @Android have u tried this, http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html I followed it properly but finding problem with R.id. the auto generated java file. Though I crossed checked it, couldn't correct them. Can u please help me out.